# Como impedir um click sobre um link/âncora ou elemento com evento amarrado

Tags: javascript, css

No caso de um link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

ou no caso de outro elemento que tenha um evento amarrado com `addEventListener`, que alternativas existem para evitar que o conteudo seja "clicado" e que isso despolete uma ação como seguir um link, abrir um select ou outra ação configurada por javascript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Uma variante é via CSS, usando [**pointer-events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

<sup>Descobrí esta maneira somente esta semana. Daí o post aqui.</sup>

Assim usando no CSS `pointer-events: none;` os cliques do mouse serão ignorados. Esta alternativa é +/- recente sendo que é suportada em elementos HTML por browsers mais modernos ( IE11+, Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 2.0+, Safari 4+).

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WMwH/)
<sub>adicionando e removendo uma classe com este CSS `pointer-events: none;`</sub>

#### Para além deste método CSS que é o mais limpo, pode obter-se o mesmo efeito usando Javascript:

No caso se ser uma tag `<a>`, `<select>` e outras tags que têm predefenido um comportamento para quando recebem um clique é preciso adicionar/amarrar um `event handler` para poder cancelar/parar o clique.

Via javascript existem algumas alternativas. Usando o `.preventDefault()` que como o nome em Inglês indica previne o comportamento por defeito.

Exemplo:

```
elemento.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Outra opção é impedir o clique com javascript criando uma variável para interceptar ou não o evento:

Assim define-se primeiro a variável e depois coloca-se um verificação do estado/valor da variável dentro da função chamada pelo click:

```
var bloqueado = true;
// dentro da função chamada pelo evento `click`
if (bloqueado) return false;
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XeEmv/)

Outra opção é remover o evento amarrado. Note-se que esta opção não se aplica a tags como `<a>`, `<select>` e outras que têm um comportamento nativo/pré-defenido quando recebem um clique.

#### Pode também usar um elemento DOM para bloquear o clique.

Uma ultima opção sugerida aqui é bloquear esse elemento com outro elemento. Usando o `z-index` é possivel sobrepôr um outro elemento, neste caso transparente para sem o utilizador se aperceber (e sem estragar o layout) sobrepôr este elemento que se quere "proteger" de cliques, ou outra interação. Note-se que esta opção impede por exemplo de selecionar texto e outros eventos em elementos que podem estar visíveis, ficando assim inacessíveis ao utilizador.

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4vcL/)

Comment: No caso do select, acho que só é possível impedir que ele abra com os *pointer-events* (belo achado!), ou sobrepondo outro elemento. Em âncoras, um preventDefault() teria o mesmo efeito, não?

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim, também achei "um bom achado". Em relação a ancoras sim, exato. Não adicionei para não fazer a resposta mais complexa com alternativas. Mas na verdade estou a pensar como adicionar visto haver boa gente que tem argumentos válidos sobre a preferência por `.preventDefault()` em vez de `return false;`

Answer (score 9):

Geralmente eu costumo utilizar o evento preventDefault, via jQuery. Veja:

```
$('.elemento').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Você clicou aqui e nada aconteceu!');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Usar o `pointer-events` é uma boa ideia se você não precisa dar suporte à versões anteriores do Internet Explorer, o que acredito não ser o caso.

Melhorando um pouco a versão do código postada pelo thiagonzalez e que funciona em todos os navegadores é:

```
$('.elemento').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
});
```

Comment: +1 por usar tanto preventDefault como returnValue caso não tenha preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Maneira diferente das anteriores, mas tambem serve para outros que não sejam links

```js
const link = document.querySelector("a");
link.onmouseenter = ()=>{
link.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
};
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```