# Desabilitar link no menu de paginação em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um plugin de paginação feito em jQuery.
O que não estou conseguindo fazer é quando estiver na última página, o link que dá acesso a próxima página seja desabilitado e o usuário não consiga clicar mais.
Da mesma maneira o botão de dá acesso a página anterior.
Já segui algumas dicas, como inserir "disable" mas isso não funciona. Some a "mãozinha" no link mas dá para clicar ainda.
O método a seguir foi criado para customizar os dois link's

```
function tagNextPrev() {
        if($nav_panels.children('.last').hasClass('active_page')){
            $nav_panels.children('.next_link').add('.last_link').removeClass('.next_link').addClass('no_more');
        } else {
            $nav_panels.children('.no_more').add('.last_link').removeClass('no_more');  
        }

        if($nav_panels.children('.first').hasClass('active_page')){
            $nav_panels.children('.previous_link').add('.first_link').addClass('no_more');
        } else {
            $nav_panels.children('.previous_link').add('.first_link').removeClass('no_more');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [**pointer-events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) para impedir o clic nos elementos que tiverem essa classe. Assim na sua classe use:

```
.no_more{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Pode lêr aqui sobre mais variantes, mas penso que CSS é a melhor, ainda que só funcione em browsers mais modernos:
[Como impedir um click sobre um link/âncora ou elemento com evento amarrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2352/como-impedir-um-click-sobre-um-link-ancora-ou-elemento-com-evento-amarrado/2353#2353)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.