# Adaptar caixas ao layout mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css3

Olá, tenho um layout que se assemelha a este

[image: Layout desktop]

Uso o Bootstrap nele.. Ao atingir um determinado breakpoint ele recebe um formato semelhante a este

[image: Layout - mobile]

Eu quero fazer o seguinte efeito, quando o layout receber a formatação demonstrada na segunda imagem, aquelas boxes verdes devem se tornar links (na versão desktop os links são apenas pequenos textos ali)..

Eu pensei em 3 possibilidades, a primeira seria usando CSS, que seria assim:
 Quando o layout chegar no breakpoint eu removo a formatação do "lado de fora" da caixa (div) e aplico ela neste link, usando media queries..

A segunda possibilidade seria usando Javascript (ou jQuery), onde eu uso um if para checar o .width() do document, se for do tamanho do breakpoint eu uso um .wrap() ou algo do tipo para transformar as caixas em links.

A terceira seria usando CSS também, onde eu adiciono duas vezes o mesmo conteúdo, um para mobile (com as caixas como links) e outro para desktop (que é o padrão mostrado na 1ª imagem) e ao chegar no breakpoint eu escondo um e mostro o outro..

Levando em consideração compatibilidade com os browsers (desktop e mobile), qual seria a melhor opção? Vocês tem outras ideias de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá uma olhada [neste post aqui](http://wpmidia.com.br/desenvolvimento-web/design-responsivo-em-3-passos/)...

Nele você vai aprender a fazer isso tudo utilizando os mesmos elementos em ambas as versões, sem ter que duplicar o conteúdo.

Ele é curto e dividido em 3 passos bem definidos: viewport, estrutura e queries.

Para desativar o link, por exemplo, basta utilizar o "pointer-events: none;" (já citado pelo Sergio) dentro da respectiva querie.

Tudo isso sem duplicar conteúdo e sem Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Sem ver o seu CSS acho que a melhor opção é ter sempre links. Na versão desktop [impede os clics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2353/129) na versão mobile: já lá estão.

Pode acrescentar isto ao CSS (para o desktop) desses elementos:

```
pointer-events: none;
```