# on() e bind() não estão funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Estou usando `off()` em um elemento para desabilitar a sua funcionalidade e preciso habilitá-lo novamente com `on()`. Mas não está funcionando quando `on()` é executado...

Aqui está o código, estou tentando prevenir que um formulário seja enviado 2 vezes quando é clicado num botão:

```
$("#meuBotao").click(function (e) {
    $(this).off("click");
    $.ajax({
    url: "/page",
    type: "POST",
    complete: function() {
                    $(this).on("click");
    },
                ...
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Eu tentei com `on()` e `off()`, e com `bind()` e `unbind()` também (que estão *deprecated* para as versões antigas agora, mas deveria funciona ainda assim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer desabilitar o botão enquanto o AJAX está rodando para o usuário não conseguir disparar várias requisições, correto? Neste caso poderia ser feito assim:

```
 $("#meuBotao").on('click',function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.prop('disabled',true); //desabilita o botão
    $.ajax({
    url: "/page",
    type: "POST",
    complete: function(){
        el.prop('disabled',false); //habilita botão novamente
    },
    //...
```

Note que eu criei uma nova variavel `el` para manusear o elemento `$(this)`, de forma que ele funcione corretamente mesmo dentro de outros escopos (como no caso da funcão disparada no `complete` do AJAX).

Eu também troquei `.click()` por `.on('click')` pelo fato de este segundo ser mais recomendado por [vários motivos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/694105).

Comment: Neste caso não faz nenhuma diferença usar `click` ou `on`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Na verdade, dando uma de chato, tem sim, é comprovado que e método `.on()` é [mais](http://www.brentsowers.com/2012/03/jquery-on-performance.html) [performático](http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-versus-click/2), portanto, mesmo sem aproveitar completamente as funcionalidades desse método, ainda é vantajoso usá-lo.

Comment: O próprio teste que você linkou mostra que isso não é verdade. Só existe diferença de performance entre usar delegação ou não.

Comment: Acho que usar `.on` ou `.click` neste caso é irrelevante e não creio ser mais recomendado aqui. O `.on` como linkou é usado para delegar eventos, que não se aplica aqui.

Comment: @Sergio o `.on` não se limita somente ao uso com delegação de eventos, na verdade o uso dele no lugar de *antigos* delegadores é até incentivado [no próprio blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) do jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

O principal problema aqui é que o `this` dentro da função ajax não é o mesmo que o `this` fora da função. O escopo é diferente... Isso tem solução fácil, que é criar uma variável intermédia que aponta para o mesmo objeto:

```
$("#meuBotao").click(function (e) {
    $(this).off("click");
    var self = this; // assim guardamos o apontador no "self"
    $.ajax({
        url: "/page",
        type: "POST",
        complete: function() {
            $(self).on("click"); // aqui usa o "self". Já agora, aqui falta a função a correr quando o click fôr gerado
        },
            ...
```

À parte desse detalhe existem outras maneiras mais usadas para impedir cliques, em vez de remover e adicionar eventos. Uma delas é criar uma flag/bandeira como propriedade no elemento ou uma variável que guarda a informação de se o elemento pode ser clicado ou não.

Um exemplo disto seria:

```
$("#meuBotao").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).data('clicavel')) return false;
    $(this).data('clicavel', false);
    var self = this; // assim guardamos o apontador no "self"
    $.ajax({
    url: "/page",
    type: "POST",
    complete: function() {
          $(self).data('clicavel', true);
    },
                ...
```

Pode inclusive fazer o mesmo adicionando CSS `pointer-events: none;` numa classe, ou diretamente no elemento. Pode ver mais ideias nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2353/129

**Nota:** no seu código `$(this).on("click");` falta o segundo parâmetro da função que indica que código correr quando o click for recebido...

Comment: Muito obrigado!