# como impedir multiplos envios de um formulario de email

Tags: jquery, formulário, formulário-submeter

Atualmente, meu formulário envia o mesmo e-mail diversas vezes, caso o usuário clique em mais de uma vez no submit. Como impeço isso? Tentei com essas duas variações do cód, mas não deu certo.

```
$("#bt-enviar").on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','true');
    $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
});
```

e

```
desab=0;    

if(desab == 1){
    $('#bt-enviar').attr('disabled','true');
    $('#bt-enviar').css('cursor', 'default');   
}

$("#bt-enviar").on('click', function() {
    desab=1;
});
```

Comment: Consegui com esse cód:

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tinha procurado muito, mas não encontrava a resposta. Consegui com esse código:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumo que esteja a fazer o envio via ajax, senão o problema não se colocaria.

Aqui o que precisa é de uma flag (sinalizador) que impeça o submit de funcionar até o ajax retornar. Já foi discutido [noutra(s) pergunta(s)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2352/129). O que lhe falta aqui é implementar isso e voltar a ativar no retorno do ajax.

Se o botão estiver dentro de uma `form`pode usar como tinha e, por exemplo, pointer events via classe:

CSS

```
.bloqueia {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bloqueia'); // ou somente o botão específico
}
```

e dentro do ajax:

```
success: function(resp){
    // ...
    $("form").removeClass('bloqueia');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se ao clicar em submit, você pode redirecionar o usuário para outra página, ou dar refresh na presente página. Isso evitará com que o usuário envie várias vezes o mesmo e-mail.

Espero que isso lhe ajude.