# O que seria o 'e' passado como parâmetro em funções js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O que seria o 'e' que é passado como parâmetro em funções? 
Ex.:

```
function nome(e) {
    (instrução);
}
```

Alguém tem algum material, ou palavra chave para pesquisa que eu possa recorrer para estudar um pouco mais sobre o assunto?

Comment: bons sites para estudar seriam: http://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/tracks/javascript e http://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/tracks/jquery

Answer (score 20, accepted):

É comum dar o nome de `e` como abreviatura de `event`, para passar uma referência ao objeto *Event* usado em [funções callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) de oscultador de eventos. Abrevia-se por comodidade e para poupar bytes.

O objeto *Event* em sí é util para por exemplo:

- no caso onde se quer [impedir um link de ser seguido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2352/como-impedir-um-click-sobre-um-link-%C3%A2ncora-ou-elemento-com-evento-amarrado/2353#2353) usa-se `e.preventDefault();` ([exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wqgrses/))
- para saber [qual o *type* de evento](http://jsfiddle.net/r66ph33j/): `e.type`
- para [saber qual o elemento clicado](http://jsfiddle.net/hkw9qsuw/) (caso seja clique) `e.target`

etc...

Comment: Valeu, Sergio! Abs.

Comment: Saquei,,, vlw man...

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso esse 'e' se trata de um parâmetro específico em funções específicas, como por exemplo, eventos.

É muito comum no jQuery. Por exemplo, quando criamos um evento de `onclick` em um link:

```
$('#link-legal').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Link legal clicado!');
});
```

Neste caso, esse parâmetro 'e' (que pode na verdade ter qualquer nome, mas é muito utilizado a letra 'e' que é abreviação de 'event') conterá o objeto do link clicado com diversas propriedades e métodos.

### Exemplo de aplicação

Digamos que você quer que, ao ser clicado em um link, seja solicitado uma confirmação ao usuário e, dependendo da resposta dele o click seja 'cancelado':

```js
$('a.confirmar').on('click', function(e) {
    var confirmado = confirm('Deseja realmente prosseguir para esse link?');
    if(confirmado == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Click cancelado');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="confirmar">Ir para o Google</a>
```

Neste exemplo utilizamos o método `preventDefault` que cancela a ação padrão do elemento, que no caso da tag `<a>` é o direcionamento para a url indicada na propriedade `href`.

---

Geralmente nas documentações você encontra esse tipo de referencia, como pode conferir na documentação oficial do jQuery para o evento `click`:

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Lá diz (em tradução livre):

> .click( handler )
>   **handler**
>   Tipo: Function( Event eventObject )
>   Uma função que será executada em cada disparo do evento.

Pode observar que no tipo ele diz que uma `Function` na qual é passado um parâmetro objeto do tipo `Event`.

Comment: Só lembrando que o objeto passado pelo jQuery não é igual ao evento nativo do JS, e sim uma versão normalizada. Ou pelo menos costumava ser assim, podem ter mudado nas versões mais recentes do jQuery.