# Só chamar a função se clicar no Parent e não nos childrens

Tags: jquery

Tenho a Seguinte div:

```
<div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

tenho uma função em `jQuery` que mostra e esconde esse menu quando clico na `div botão`, tenho duas condições para esconder esse sub menu, ou clicando na `div botão` ou clicando na própria `div sub-menu` usando essa função:

```
  $(".sub-menu").click(function(){
    if(status == 1){
        $('.sub-menu').animate({
            left: '-224px',                     
        }, 300);    
        $('.fade').fadeOut();
        status = 0;
        $('.hamburg').removeClass('open');            
    }    
  });
```

a variável `status` verifica se o `sub-menu` esta aberto ou fechado, o problema é que quando clico nas `li's` dentro do `sub-menu` ele ignora os link e apenas fecha a div `sub-menu`, como fazer ele readicionar normalmente para as supostas paginas ao clicar nos links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando usas `$(".sub-menu").click(function(){` essa função anónima ([callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129)) vai ser chamada quando um elemento com a classe `sub-menu` receber um evento. O que é interessante e útil aqui é que essa callback [disponibiliza um argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61212/129), o evento em sí e corre com o contexto apontado ao elemento. Ou seja, o `this` dentro dessa função é o proprio elemento cujo `.click(` foi aplicado.

O objeto evento que é passado à callback tem uma propriedade importante que é o `.target`, ou seja o elemento onde o `click` se deu. Ora isso é a resposta à tua dúvida:

Quando o `this` e o `e.target` forem o mesmo o click deu-se no `.sub-menu` e não num descendente. Podes testar isso aqui (vê a consola): https://jsfiddle.net/pLgL82pk/

Assim no código podes ter:

```
$(".sub-menu").click(function(e){
    if (e.target == this){
        // o click deu-se no sub-menu
    } else {
        // o click deu-se num descendente
    }
    // etc...
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente meu caro, não tinha conhecimento disso, muito obrigado!